# Simple Chrome Content Script Not Running

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-script

I wrote a short content script, which stops a particular site from creating new windows for link clicks.

This is my first Chrome extension, and I've scored this website and the internet for a reason why it won't run, but I can't find any. I'm probably making a fundamental amateur mistake somewhere.

Manifest.json:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "DHS Links",
"description": "Stops the school's site from constantly opening new windows.",
"version": "1.0",

"browser_action": {
"default_icon": "icon.png"
},

"content_scripts":[
  {
    "matches": ["*://www.darienps.org/dhs/*"],
    "js": ["jquery.js", "makeNormalLinks.js"],
    "run_at": "document_end"

  }
 ]
}
```

I tested the Javascript file by itself on a local version of the site, so I'm pretty sure it's fine, but just in case:

makeNormalLinks.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a").each(function(){
        $(this).removeAttr("onclick");
    });
});
```

A copy of jQuery is in the same directory and doesn't seem to have any issues.

Here's the onclick code for many links on the website:

`onclick="window.open(this.href,'targetWindow','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,')`

Thank you for looking this over!

---

Edit:

I tried two of the injection methods from [Rob W's response to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script) linked to in the comments by Teepeemm.

Here's the new code for Method 1:

Manifest.json:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "DHS Links",
"description": "Stops the school's site from constantly opening new windows.",
"version": "1.0",

"browser_action": {
"default_icon": "icon.png"
},

"content_scripts":[
  {
    "matches": ["*://www.darienps.org/dhs/*"],
    "js": ["jquery.js", "scriptLauncher.js"]

  }
 ],
"web_accessible_resources": ["makeNormalLinks.js"]
}
```

scriptLauncher.js:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
// TODO: add "script.js" to web_accessible_resources in manifest.json
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL('makeNormalLinks.js');
s.onload = function() {
this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
};
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
```

Method 2a:

(Uses old Manifest.js)

makeNormalLinks.js:

```
var actualCode = ['$(document).ready(function(){',
                  '$("a").each(function(){',
                  '$(this).removeAttr("onclick");',
                  '});',
                  '});'].join('\n');

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.textContent = actualCode;
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
script.parentNode.removeChild(script);
```

Unfortunately, neither method seems to work. I'm extremely grateful to those who commented and think we're getting close to an answer.

---

Solution:

Manifest.json:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "DHS Links",
"description": "Stops the school's site from constantly opening new windows.",
"version": "1.0",

"browser_action": {
"default_icon": "icon.png"
},

"content_scripts":[
  {
    "matches": ["*://www.darienps.org/dhs/*"],
    "js": ["makeNormalLinks.js"]

  }
 ]
}
```

makeNormalLinks.js:

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
}, true);
```

Thanks you, Scott and all who commented!

Comment: `$("document").ready(function(){` should probably be `$(document).ready(function(){`, or just `$(function(){`.

Comment: I can't believe I made that mistake. Thanks for catching it! Unfortunately, the extension still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Unrelated, but you don't need "browser_action" or "permissions" to do this.  And "document_end" is the default, and can be omitted.

Comment: How are the links created?  If `a onclick=`, then I think this would work.  But if it's `a href="" target="_blank"` or `$("a")[0].attachEventListener`, then you may need a different approach.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, Teepee! I left the browser_action in to keep my spiffy logo though. I'll update the main post with a removal of the permissions bit and the onclick code.

Comment: Could `onclick` counts as the page’s javascript, and not its DOM? If so, you’re getting caught by [isolated worlds](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment).  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879/2336725) for what to do.

Incidentally, welcome to SO.  A feature I’ll share is if you type @ before you start typing a username, the server will complete the username for you.  This has the advantage of avoiding misspellings (e.g., you left off “mm” ;)) and typing non-ascii characters that some people use.  It also notifies the other person: @Nick

Comment: For example, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24752464/2336725) just popped up, and has the same symptoms.

Comment: I tried two of the injection methods and will update the main post with the code. No successes, but I feel like I'm on the right track. @Teepeemm

Comment: It appears that on their site, `$` is for Mootools, so you would need to change `$` to `jQuery` in your latter attempts.  The weird thing is that all three of these do remove the `onclick` attribute, but the windows still open.  Go with ScottF's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `onclick` attribute has many weird side effects. A more up to date approach would be to add a listener to the document that filters unwanted events. Like:

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
}, true);
```

The `true` argument is important (see event capture). This will block all click event listeners from firing, but the default click action will still be triggered.

Comment: It worked! The method doesn't even require injecting the script or jQuery. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similiar issue getting the content script to fire in Google Mail. I stumbled upon a page that recommended using the "hashchange" event.

```
// Event listener
window.addEventListener("hashchange", function () {
  alert("hashchanged");
}, false);
```

Comment: You should probably indicate if this will help OP and how