# Remove a "onmousedown" event from a DOM element via content script in Google Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm trying to write a Google Chrome extension that removes the `onmousedown` event from a `<a>` tag on a website.

Earlier that site used to have `onmousedown` event as part of the DOM so I could easily remove it via content script by calling `element.removeAttribute("onmousedown")`. 
But now, they add that event via javascript so it's not possible for me directly remove that event via `content script` as it runs in a different javascript context.

PS: I'm specifically talking about `onmousedown` event on links on google search results page. Earlier, this [small piece of code](https://github.com/shadyabhi/GSanitizer/blob/master/sanitize.js#L24-L27) used to work but now it doesn't as `onmousedown` is not part of the DOM now.

```
var all_main_links = document.getElementsByClassName("r");
for (i=0; i<all_main_links.length; i++){
    var current_link = all_main_links[i].childNodes[0];
    current_link.removeAttribute("onmousedown");
    }
```

Comment: Take a look at [injecting your code into the page's context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script). It may be the only way.

Comment: I've been puzzling over [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24718605/2336725), and @Xan may have figured out what was going on.

Comment: @Xan That link definitely helped and solved my issues. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

A content script cannot access in page javascript object (such as onmousedown event declared by javascript). They're executed in a sandbox.

But what you can do is inserting a script in the head of the page (with script tag) wich shutdown the event :)